# Check for changes after update

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to check if values from a table were changed after the update process and store the `sysdate` in a column. For updating, I'm using a stored procedure with more than 60 parameters (number of columns from my table). The stored procedure is called every time a user hit the button save in the UI. Does anyone know how can I achieve this?
I mention that I can't use triggers because of the performance policy.
Thank You!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why can't your stored procedure simply include the 'LAST_MODIFIED' column (or whatever its name is) in the UPDATE statement, setting it to SYSTIMESTAMP?

Comment: Can you capture the row into a local variable before updating, and compare the parameter values to that?

Comment: I can't include the last modified column because the stored procedure updates always all columns from my table... And to capture all rows in a variable I have to make more than 60 if statements. Of course, I can do that but if someone adds a new column to my table will be forced to make a new if everytime...

Comment: When a new column is added you will have to edit the procedure anyhow.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand: do you want the LAST_MODIFIED to be updated only if at least one column was actually changed?

Comment: Yes, I want to store the `sysdate` in a column, if at least one of my column were modified after the update.

Comment: Create a trigger on your table for update. Whenever any update occurs insert a record to some table for logging with sysdate

Comment: Just a small note that doesn't answer your question: use `SYSTIMESTAMP` instead of `SYSDATE` if you're interested in a more accurate timestamp.

Comment: @XING: OP mentioned he cannot use triggers

Comment: @RobertKock As far as i know..triggers has nothing to do with performance. I mean if there is a easy way available one should use it.

Comment: If you want to check before or during the update, you need to check in the stored procedure.  If you want to check after the update, you need a trigger.  If you can't use triggers, you're left with the stored procedure.  If you don't like that approach, but have no other option, you still have no other option.  As pointed out already, the concern about having to edit the SP after new columns are added is mute; the SP will need editing to account for the new column anyway...

Comment: @XING: I know that triggers are ok in this situation...but the Oracle team of our client banned this kind of things...

Comment: Ok, thank you guys a lot for helping me :) I will modified the SP. And sorry for the long list of replies.